# Counting in Arduino making nonsens numbers

Tags: time, arduino, int, arduino-ide

I want to convert entered time date to seconds.

```
    case 1:
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Nastavte zacatek");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("                    ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Hodina: ");
    while (U == true && ch < 24) {
      ch++; //ch stands for hour variable, it is integer
      U = false;
      lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
      lcd.print(ch);
    }
```

and I am counting with this:

```
 zacatek = ((ch * 3600) + (cm * 60) + cs);
```

zacatek is unsigned long, cm and cs are entered same way as ch(but in other case).
Then I print it on Serial using  `Serial.println(zacatek);`
But for example, for time 20:0:0(ch = 20, cm = 0, cs = 0) it returns me 6464.
Or, for time 19:16:0 it returns me 3824.
Can someone say me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int value is 16bits wide on most Arduino Boards, so if you multiply `3600*20` you'll get number much bigger than `65535` which is maximal value for the uint16_t. However, if you substract `72000 - 65536` you'll get value `6464`. Btw: signed integer overflow behavior is undefined by C++ specification (it's platform dependent), but it usually overflows as  `32767` to `-1`  and `-32768` to `0`

If you need bigger values, use `int32_t` or `uint32_t` instead. For constants `INT32_C(3600) * ch` or  `UINT32_C(3600) * ch` can be used - if you don't want to change datatype for `ch`.

Comment: Ohh, thank, I knew there was an overflow, but I didn't know where. Now working perfectly. Thank you very much.